# Is it possible to assign to a (public or private) class member an initial value using a static method from another class?

Tags: c#, static

say I have the following class

```
public class MyClass1 {

        protected static int MyIntName1 = 0;

        public static int GetMyIntName1() {
                return MyIntName1;
        }

        public void MyMethod1() {
                MyIntName1 += 1;
        }
}
```

I then have a second class which has a private static int member for which I want to assign as initial value the value of MyIntName1 of the first class. Is there a way to do that ? Does the fact of being private or public make any difference actually ? I tried to do the following

```
public class MyClass2 {

    private static int MyIntName2 = MyClass1.GetMyIntName1(); /* Here the value of MyIntName2
    is assigned 0 not matter which value MyIntName1 could have */

    public void MyMethod2() {
            MyIntName2 = MyClass1.GetMyIntName1(); /*If I do this then MyIntName2 gets
            the value of MyIntName1 but that holds only in this method and I would have to
            repeat this in any other method of this class that requires the value of MyIntName1...*/
    }
}
```

but no value is assigned to `MyIntName2`. However, if I do the same inside of a method of the second class, the value of `MyIntName1` is assigned but that would only hold in that particular method. To be honest, I am not even sure that what I am trying to achieve makes any sense since I already have a static method which I am trying to assign at declaration to another static member inside a different class. It may be that there is no real purpose in doing this as I could just use the getter method from `MyClass1` wherever I need it... However, I am wondering which are all the possibilities of assigning an initial value to class member. Forgive me if the question has already been asked of this does not make any sense.

Thank you.

Comment: In your example `MyIntName2` is set to zero and will always be zero, what about  the code doesn't work?

Comment: @JSteward You are right I forgot to mention that there are methods in MyClass1 that may modify MyInt1. Let me edit the question. Thanks !

Comment: Are you expecting `MyIntName2` to change whenever `MyIntName1` does? You're only assigning it once, when `MyClass2` is initialized.

Comment: @madreflection No, I'm just expecting `MyIntName2` to be assigned at declaration the value of `MyIntName1`

Comment: You've already done it as close to *"at declaration"* as can be semantically mapped and that's why it's always `0`.

Comment: @madreflection I'm sorry I don't get your answer, can you elaborate more please ?

Comment: You need to provide a [mre] that shows how you intend to use this and what you expect to change (or not change) as it's being used. There's a latent misconception that's confusing the issue and there's not enough information yet to reveal it.

Comment: Also, you said *"if I do the same inside of a method of the second class"* but you didn't provide *that* code and it's unclear what you mean by that. Be sure to include that when you [edit] the question with the minimal reproducible example.

Comment: @madreflection Thank you for your answer and time. I tried to add so more info so it hopefully is more clear.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213867/discussion-between-chiva-and-madreflection).